# Data not showing in datatable LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript

My data is not showing in the datatable, as far as I was able to unit test this, the fieldsNames aren't mapping correctly but I cannot work out the solution.

Datatable.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card  title="">
      <div class="slds-box slds-theme_shade">
        <div>
          <lightning-datatable
                  key-field="id"
                  data={data}
                  columns={convertColumns}
                  hide-checkbox-column="true"
                  resize-column-disabled="true"
                  min-column-width="80"
                  max-column-width="100"
                  show-row-number-column="true">
          </lightning-datatable>
      </div>
      </div>
    </lightning-card>  
  </template>
```

Datatable.js

```
    this.mustHaveSessionLabelColumns = [
      "Session ID",
      "Visitor ID",
      "Timestamp"
  ];
    this._selectedDimensions.forEach(row => {
    this.mustHaveSessionLabelColumns.push(row);
    });
    this.mustHaveSessionLabelColumns.forEach(i => {
      this.convertColumns.push({label: this.mustHaveSessionLabelColumns[i],
        fieldName: this.convertedColumns[i],
        type: "text",
        editable: false,
        displayReadOnlyIcon: true,
        cellAttributes: { alignment: "center" },
        sortable: true,
        wrapText: true});
      });
      alert("Label:" + this.convertColumns[0].label);
    fetchSessions({
       webSiteId: this.accName,
       selectedSiteName:this.scopeSelectedSite,
       stringColumns: this._selectedDimensions,
       date_from: this.scopeStartDate,
       date_to: this.scopeEndDate,
       token: this.apexResponse.data
     }).then(response => {
               let responseData = JSON.parse(response);
               var data = [];
               responseData.data.forEach(row => {
                 let newRow = {};
                     row.forEach((element, index) => {
                   newRow[this.convertColumns[index].fieldName] = element;
                 });
                 data.push(newRow);
               });
               this.data_Datatable = data;
               alert("Data" + this.data_Datatable);
           })
           .catch(error => {
               this.error = error;
           });
  }
```

[image]
What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: So,you have a variable to store results called `this.data_Datatable`.
And from the html, you get the data from a variable called `{data}` ?

Comment: @NicolásMaldonado  I'm using variable 'data' for storing the new row in tje forEach loop, but you're right this.data_Datatable is useless variable. Sorry for confusing code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, as I mentioned it - fieldNames of the columns were not setting correctly.